# Can't create a formula in excel to satisfy certain conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a formula in excel using IF condition so that it adds `6` to the beginning of an existing number starting with `0`, as in `0124685515`. However, when the number starts with `1`, the formula should add `60` to the beginning of the existing number. Otherwise, the number should be left untouched.

To be more specific:

`124685515` will be `60124685515`

`0124685515` will turn into `60124685515`

`60124685515` should be `60124685515`

My current attempt:

`=IF(LEFT(A1,1)=0,"6"&A1,IF(LEFT(A1,1)=1,"60"&A1,A1))`

How can I modify the formula to meet the above conditions?

Comment: What is the current output of your function on your given test values?

Comment: When I used that formula to change this `124685515` to `60124685515`, I got `124685515`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the 'numbers' are actually strings (i.e. text). If that's true:
a) If you want a textual result, alter your formula per:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="0","6"&A1,IF(LEFT(A1,1)="1","60"&A1,A1))
```

b) Alternately:

```
=IF(LEN(A3)<11,TEXT(A3+60000000000,0),A3)
```

c) If you want a numeric result: see @P.b's response

Comment: Edited my answer to have a textual or numeric solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

`=IF(LEN(A1)=11,A1+0,A1+60000000000)`

Or if you want to stick to text: `=TEXT(IF(LEN(A1)=11,A1+0,A1+60000000000),"@")`